# creating subgraphs of a given graph in another location and make use of them for querying

Tags: neo4j

I want to know whether we can create a sub graph of a given graph in neo4j and cache it in some place and later use this sub graph and later update it on the main graph etc...

```
match (n)-[r:knows]-(m) return {node:n,neighbours:collect({type:type(r),node1:m})}

UNWIND { neighbours } AS neighbours

create (node)-[:neighbours.type]->(node1)        // as a new graph without merging to                                                                                          
                                                 // the original graph with another name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to Neo4j itself but give the nodes an additional label, so you create kind of a namespace that you would use during querying.